# SQL query to test my programming capabilities in different way

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2005

I have one table and one column in it. There is 15 rows (integers). I want to count
the positive numbers and negative numbers, and also sum of total numbers in one query.

Can any one help me?

Comment: Number of positive numbers or (as some of the answerers have assumed), sum of all the positive numbers?

Comment: @bortzmeyer, OP said: _i want to count positive numbers and negative numbers_

Answer (score 3):

Or...

```
SELECT  
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Col > 0 THEN 1 END) AS NumPositives,
     COUNT(CASE WHEN Col < 0 THEN 1 END) AS NumNegatives,
     SUM(Col) AS Tot
FROM  TableName;
```

Or you could consider using SIGN(Col), which gives 1 for positive numbers and -1 for negative numbers.

Comment: I initially up-voted for this, but took back the up vote, when I noticed the COUNT(), I was thinking SUM().  After testing, I see it works, but couldn't up-vote unless question was edited, so I edited.

Comment: I used COUNT because it fits the problem most closely. By having no ELSE clause, I only count the ones that meet the criteria.

Answer (score 1):

I'll give you psudeo code to help you with your homework.

3 aggregates:

- SUM
- SUM (CASE < 0)
- SUM (CASE > 0)

Answer (score 1):

```
select (select sum(mycolumn) from mytable where mycolumn > 0) as positive_sum,
       (select sum(mycolumn) from mytable where mycolumn < 0) as negative_sum,
       sum(mycolumn) as total_sum
from   mytable
```

Comment: OP said: _i want to count positive numbers and negative numbers_ you SUM them

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
SELECT  SUM(CASE WHEN Col > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Pos,
        SUM(CASE WHEN Col < 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Neg,
        SUM(Col) AS Tot
FROM    Table
```

Comment: if OP wants count of Pos and Neg, you need to change _THEN Col ELSE 0_ to _THEN 1 ELSE 0_