# Sql query to alter table

Tags: sql, mysql

I have two tables **miusernames** with columns where UserNamesID is the primary key for table miusernames..

```
UserNamesID       UserName  
1                  senthil

2                  robert
```

and **miemailids** with columns where Emailid  is the primary key for table miemailids ..

```
Emailid   UserNamesID  
1             2
```

I forgot to create column UserNamesID  in table miemailids as foreign key relationship with parent table miusernames .. I need values of column UserNamesID  in table miemailids should not be the values other than values in UserNamesID  column in parent table miusernames.

I need help in alter table miemailids as adding foreign key relationship for column UserNamesID  with parent table miusernames.. Help me with the query to alter table..I feel good if i get exact query.. thanx in advance

Comment: is this you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1431156?

Answer (score 3):

```
ALTER TABLE miemailids
ADD FOREIGNKEY (UserNamesID) REFERENCES miusernames(UserNamesID)
```

should do it if you are on mysql and MSSQL

```
ALTER TABLE miemailids
ADD (CONSTRAINT fk_UserNamesID) FOREIGN KEY (UserNamesID) REFERENCES miusernames(UserNamesID);
```

should do it on Oracle

Comment: Hi ,
I am using mysql only. If i put your above code i am getting syntax error as check for the right syntax to use near  (UserNamesID).. How to solve this ?